# Cheapest way to build or buy a remote controlled sound maker?

Tags: sound, device

For my high school class's senior prank, we'd like to buy cheap prepaid cell phones (like these: http://bit.ly/VSqOk3), hide them in the ceiling tiles, and then call then randomly throughout the day. However this gets expensive quickly. Is there a cheaper way to build or buy something with similar functionality? It doesn't necessarily even need to be remote controlled if it could be programmed to go off at certain times.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fED9ts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming you buy about 25 of each:

An Attiny is about $1. A small speaker is about $2. A MOSFET to drive it is about $0.25. A small 3.7V LiPo battery is about $2. The Atmega can run on the built-in ceramic resonator at 1 MHz or 8 MHz when fed 3V or better. 1 MHz (and perhaps sleep mode) will extend the lifetime, although you'll likely get a couple of days of battery life even without that.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATTINY85-20PU/ATTINY85-20PU-ND/735469
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/2403%20260%2000031/423-1172-1-ND/3854653
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BS170/BS170-ND/244280
http://www.hobbypartz.com/250mah.html

The Attiny can be programmed to wait for a random amount of time, and then make a noise on the output pin that drives the MOSFET/speaker. You'll need a USB programmer and a socket to program the chips in, which adds about $10 of one-time cost.

[http://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Programmer-ATMEL-ATMega-ATTiny/dp/B0051SRZWC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051SRZWC)

plus a breadboard and some jumper wires for programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `cricket` or `annoying sound` circuit. They beep once every few minutes or so, drives people insane. The other option, for specific times, is using a microcontroller running as a timer, connected to a buzzer. Between the microcontroller , a battery, a buzzer, and some passives, it should only be a few bucks.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontroller, buzzer/beeper/bell/siren device (you can buy them that make a variety of fixed function sounds once you provide a DC power source to them), battery, and voltage regulator for making the microcontroller / buzzer work given the battery voltage.
One combination that comes to mind is the MSP430Gxxx MCU (could be any device in the series e.g. MSP430G2452 in a DIP pacakge), a 9V battery + snap connector + leads, and a 9V in 3.3V or 3.6V output voltage regulator for the MCU.  Use a NPN transistor like the PN2222 with emitter grounded, the base hooked through a 1K resistor to the MCU output pin, the collector to the negative buzzer lead, and the positive buzzer lead going to the positive battery terminal or the voltage regulator output depending on whether the buzzer takes 9V or 3.3V to operate.  Voltage regulator IN terminal = battery positive terminal, voltage regulator ground terminal = battery negative terminal.  Voltage regulator output terminal = MCU positive supply terminal and maybe also the buzzer positive supply if it is a 3.3VDC buzzer.
Program the MCU to generate whatever pattern of delays you want. Use the $4.30 TI MSP430 "Launchpad" named development kit to program the chip in a 14 or 20 pin DIP package.
Put a 10uF 16VDC or higher capacitor as follows: negative = battery GROUND, positive = battery positive.
Put a 10uF 16VDC or higher capacitor as follows: negative = battery GROUND, positive = voltage regulator positive output.
Should be about $5 or less worth of parts for the unit if you wire it up on protoboard and buy the parts at DigiKey.  More like $10 if you shop at radio shack, though they probably don't sell MCUs other than a $40 arduino kit or something.  Fry's would work.
Make a dozen or so PCBs at OSHPARK if you want to make the wiring easier.
Buzzers that can work at 3V or some higher:
http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff4000b%2Cfff80047%2C1c0002%2C1c0003%2C8e4006c%2C8e4007a%2C8e400d7%2C8e400d8%2C8e400dd%2C8e400de%2C8e400fb%2C8e4018f%2C8e401f0%2C8e401f2%2C8e401f3%2C8e401fa%2C8e401fc%2C8e401fd%2C8e401fe%2C8e40201%2C8e40202%2C8e40203%2C8e40205%2C8e4020c%2C8e40210%2C8e40213%2C8e40215%2C8e4021a%2C8e40221%2C8e40225%2C8e4022e%2C8e40233%2C8e4023c%2C8e4023d%2C8e4023f%2C8e40242%2C8e40243%2C8e40244%2C8e40245%2C8e40246%2C8e40247%2C8e40248%2C8e40249%2C8e4024c%2C8e4024e%2C8e40250%2C8e40252%2C8e40262&k=buzzer&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0

Capacitors:
http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40002%2Cfff80009&k=10uF+electrolytic&vendor=0&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ptm=0&fid=0&quantity=0&PV63=449&PV63=489&PV63=490&PV63=431&PV63=371&PV63=466&PV63=494&PV63=491&PV63=498&PV63=428&PV69=80&PV7=3&stock=1&rohs=1

Transistor:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PN2222ATA/PN2222ATACT-ND/3042489

Microcontroller :
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MSP430G2102IN20/296-29639-5-ND/2597166

Launchpad programming kit (might be a little cheaper at TI's web store if the shipping is still free there):
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MSP-EXP430G2/296-27570-ND/2331789

Regulator:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MCP1702-3302E%2FTO/MCP1702-3302E%2FTO-ND/1098463

Resistor:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1-1625875-2/A106014CT-ND/3477630

You probably don't really need a capacitor across the battery, or, for that matter across the regulator 3V output though one is recommended there.

The code here will delay a while and then turn on the PORT1 bits which would enable the buzzer.

How long is a while?  Well figure it out.  Start with a smaller number like 1000000L and see how long that takes and extrapolate from there.  Don't be debugging the MCU while checking the speed or it'll throw off the timing results.  Set the MCU to run at some frequency like 32kHz or 1MHz or 8MHz, doesn't matter much, just adjust the timing to suit the loop speed.  Oh some regulators want a minimum load of a milliamp or two to regulate properly, so maybe run at 8MHz to satisfy that if needed or use a regulator with no minimum load required.
Source code:
unsigned long count;
main() { count = 20000000L; P1OUT=0x00; while(--count); P1OUT=0xff; for(;;); }

Or, hmm, much easier -- buy some digital clocks or watches or timed alarms at dealextreme (dx.com) or focalprice.com or similar.  I'm guessing about $0.25 a piece by the dozen, but, then, that's not an electronics engineering solution, so it wouldn't be as pertinent as the above here.